# Not able to push to local registry with podman

Tags: docker, ansible, registry, podman

I'm trying to push some images to my local registry as i did with docker but it's not working.

What i'm doing:

- `podman pull hello-world` from internet
- `podman tag feb5d9fea6a5 127.0.0.1:5030/hello-world` my registry is up on port 5030
- `podman --log-level=debug push --tls-verify=false localhost:5030/hello-world` --> stuck on "Getting image source signatures" and show DEBU[0010] GET http://localhost:5030/v2/ with debug mode

Curl show this:

```
[root@xxx]# curl -vvvv http://localhost:5030/v2/_catalog

* About to connect() to localhost port 5030 (#0)

* Trying 127.0.0.1...

* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5030 (#0)

> GET /v2/_catalog HTTP/1.1

> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0

> Host: localhost:5030

> Accept: */*

>
```

Added registries to /etc/containers/registries.conf:

```
[registries.insecure]

registries = ['localhost:5030', '127.0.0.1:5030']
```

Reset my http and https_proxy variable to blank

Have you an idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved !

Error in my ansible playbook at port declaration for the container.

Use argument "ports: 0.0.0.0:5030:5000" instead of "ports: 5030:5000" also know as "publish" argument

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).